# English word that describes the doer of uncompleted work?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that describes someone who does all the work that is unfinished by others once they do their work.

Comment: Can you disclose the nature of the task? e.g. is it janitorial etc.?

Comment: it is office work that is not completed by other workers

Comment: In baseball it's called *the closer*. In my line of work it's called the [swearword] who 'gets' to finish it. Or the guy who gets to fix some [swearword's] mistakes. I often get to be that guy. *"Keep firing, [swearwords!]"*

Comment: @Mazura not sure what the word is since it is changed to [swearword], but closer is a good start

Comment: Type into Google *keep firing* and hit the spacebar, and it should come up. It's a quote from Spaceballs.

Comment: got it, can't use that at work :)

Comment: In the UK, postmen have a [***sweeper***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sweeper) who does the work for others on their day off, or if they can't do their allocated work because of illness or whatever. And a sweeper in soccer supports the main defenders, as by intercepting loose balls, etc., so that's kinda like "doing the odd jobs to finish up". Also on building sites you might tell one labourer to ***sweep up*** after the main crew have done some job, where it just means "tidy up, clean & put the tools away / check for anything left undone", even if there's no reason to use a broom.

Comment: @CruncherBigData Would you settle for something that means " A worker who takes on the responsibilities of others." That is, if you consider it even a little bit close at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about "task-mopper"?

It's rather informal, but it should convey the message.

Comment: brilliant suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I use the fourth definition/usage of [Fall guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_guy).

The most likely origin of "fall guy" is a derivation of the slang 'fall' which means to be arrested, so the fall guy is generally the one who is arrested.[3] However, four slightly different usages for "fall guy" survive and their origins are probably different. These usages are:

> An innocent scapegoat is unjustly punished for another's action.
>
> A guilty scapegoat takes the blame for the actions of a group.
>
> A dupe takes the butt of jokes.
>
> A worker who takes on the responsibilities of others.